# Using the Residue theorem to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{(x+1)^{3}}dx$.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I need help to evaluate the integral 
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{(x+1)^{3}}dx
\end{align*}
using the Residue theorem. 
I think that I could consider the contour integral
\begin{align*}
\oint_{C}\frac{\ln(z)}{(z+1)^{3}}dz,
\end{align*}
where $C$ is the quarter circle in the upper-right quadrant. But I'm not sure how to continue.

Could someone help me?

Comment: I suggest to use the logarithm with $[0,+\infty[$ as the branch cut and then use a pacman contour.

Comment: the integral should be $$-\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: Could you please explain further. How do I set up the pacman contour?

Answer (score 2):

Take the function $$f\left(z\right)=\frac{\log^{2}\left(z\right)}{\left(1-z\right)^{3}}$$ and the branch of the logarithm corresponding to $-\pi<\arg\left(z\right)\leq\pi$. Take the keyhole contour and define $\Gamma$ and $\gamma$ respectively the large circumference of radius $R$ and the small circumference of radius $\rho$ (see [here](https://www.google.it/search?q=keyhole+contour&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjKgdbawr_SAhXrNJoKHfKwCQMQ_AUICSgC&biw=1366&bih=662#imgrc=b9MQhIBq0M8u8M:)).
It is not difficult to prove that the integrals over the circumferences vanish so $$2\pi i\underset{z=1}{\textrm{Res}}\left(f\left(z\right)\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log^{2}\left(-x+i\epsilon\right)}{\left(x-i\epsilon+1\right)^{3}}dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log^{2}\left(-x-i\epsilon\right)}{\left(x+i\epsilon+1\right)^{3}}dx$$ $$\stackrel{\epsilon\rightarrow0}{\rightarrow}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\log\left(x\right)+i\pi\right)^{2}}{\left(x+1\right)^{3}}dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\log\left(x\right)-i\pi\right)^{2}}{\left(x+1\right)^{3}}dx$$ $$=4\pi i\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log\left(x\right)}{\left(x+1\right)^{3}}dx$$ and since $$\underset{z=1}{\textrm{Res}}\left(f\left(z\right)\right)=-1$$ we get $$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log\left(x\right)}{\left(x+1\right)^{3}}dx=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$

We can also use real methods. Note that $$I\left(a\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{a}}{\left(x+1\right)^{3}}dx=B\left(a+1,-a+2\right),\,-1<a<2$$ where $B(x,y)$ is the [beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html) so $$I'\left(a\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log\left(x\right)x^{a}}{\left(x+1\right)^{3}}dx=\left(\psi\left(a+1\right)-\psi\left(2-a\right)\right)B\left(a+1,-a+2\right)$$ where $\psi\left(x\right)$ is the [digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html) hence $$I=\lim_{a\rightarrow0}\left[\left(\psi\left(a+1\right)-\psi\left(2-a\right)\right)B\left(a+1,-a+2\right)\right]=\color{blue}{-\frac{1}{2}}.$$

Comment: So you mean that we get by the residue theorem that $2\pi i Res(f,1)=\int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz+\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz+\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x)dx+\int_{\infty}^{0}f(x)dx$, then $\int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz$ and $\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz$ vanish?

Comment: @Math The limits $R \rightarrow \infty$ and $\rho \rightarrow 0$  give $0$ as result. If you want I can write the calculations.

Comment: Do you mean like this: On $\Gamma$ we have $\int_{\Gamma}f(z)dz=\frac{\ln^{2}(R)}{(1-R)^{3}}2\pi R \to 0$ when $R\to \infty$. And simiarly when we look at $\gamma$ but we take $\rho \to 0$?

Comment: @Math No. On $\Gamma$ you have to put $z=R e^{i \theta}$ and on $\gamma$ you have to put $z= \rho e^{i \theta}$. Then take the absolute value of the integrals. It is possible to find an upper bound that does not depend on $\theta$ but only on $R$ and $\rho$ such that the limits go to $0$. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan's_lemma

Comment: Okey thank you for your help!

Comment: One more question, now I understand how to prove the integrals over the circumference vanishes. But could you help me understand how and why you put $z=-x+i\epsilon$ and $z=-x-i\epsilon$ on the other 2 integrals? I don't really understand.

Comment: @Math Did you see the contour I posted in the link? There are two segments with different orientation, one from the left to the right and one from the right to the left.  Also one of them is a bit above the real line (call $\epsilon$ this distance) and the other is a bit below the real line.

Comment: Yes now I understand. Thanks again!